# Add items to array with a search

Tags: android, arrays, listview, azure-sql-database

I am busy creating an application where i would like to store all items which the user has searched for in an array and then display it. When i run my code i get the following error:

```
Process: com.digitialninja.mohammed.curtainclub, PID: 15718
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:100)
   at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:556)
   at com.digitalninja.mohammed.curtainclub.Srail$1.onClick(Srail.java:60)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I am using an SQL query where it checks in my azure database for the records and then logically it must add it to an array, and from there my custom listview should show all the searched items. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.srail, container, false);
    search = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    Esearch = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.srch);
    list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.raill);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
            checkLogin.execute("");

            List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;

            String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","RANGE","SUPPLIER","SIZE" };

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.Range_txtView,R.id.size_txtView,R.id.supplier_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_products, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    HashMap<String,Object> obj=(HashMap<String,Object>)ADAhere.getItem(position);
                    String ID=(String)obj.get("A");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}


public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Searching...",
                "Listview Loading! Please Wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isSuccess) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Search Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            //finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String Search = search.getText().toString();


        if (Search.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please Search something";
        else {
            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            try {
                ConnectionHelper conStr = new ConnectionHelper();
                connect = conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
                if (connect == null) {
                    z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                } else {
                    // Change below query according to your own database.
                    String query = "select * from cc_rail where rail_name='" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_UNIT_PRICE= '" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_RANGE= '" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_SUPPLIER='" + Search.toString() + "' OR RAIL_SIZE='" + Search.toString() + "'";
                    Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        datanum.put("NAME", rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                        datanum.put("PRICE", rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                        datanum.put("RANGE", rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                        datanum.put("SUPPLIER", rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                        datanum.put("SIZE", rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                        data.add(datanum);
                    }


                    z = " successful";
                    isSuccess = true;
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }

            return String.valueOf(data);
        }
        return z;
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the stack trace of the exception, it is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

A `NullPointerException` is thrown when you try to access a method or property on a `null` object.

After reviewing your code, i think the exception is arising because you're passing `MyData` as `null` to a method.

i think initialising the `MyData` object would fix the exception.

Something like this:
`List<Map<String,String>> MyData = new ArrayList();`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;

ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_products, fromwhere, viewswhere);
```

In these two lines from OnCreateView() method, **MyData is null and you are passing it to SimpleAdapter**.

Just **populate MyData with appropriate data** and your problem should be resolved.